# The type is resolved according to what rules or priority in declare syntax?

Tags: typescript, types

**env:**

typescript: 4.4.4

**Note:**

Different function definition methods

arg2: () = {}, arg3(){}, arg4: function() {}
Maybe they have different priority? I don't know!

**Link:**

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwwE8AHEAZwB4BBAPgAoAoeeWAczIC54BveJ5ljFYBGLlQA0-ZmwBMXOgEp4AXhrwJUwawDM8pavWSBWgCx6VajcwC+DJVwBuOLMADcDBgHpP8UJFgIKOjYeAQk5NT0Xj7SQpw80cZacvCKFoaJxmyiGd5JbLqp+paSeVlCZkXpGmXwtnn28E4u7gxEpGR03PzZXADkiGTAfUbJ5gbdxnAYyDD4wjL81qMFaZMC07P4ANoDfQC6SysVXEGYuKhrmptzBDDIIEcM1goebwxAA

```
// 1
declare function types<A>(
  args: { 
    arg1: A,
    arg2: () => A,
    arg3: () => A,
    arg4: () => A,
  }
) : void;

// 2
declare function types<A>(
  args: { 
    arg2: () => A,
    arg1: A,
    arg3: () => A,
    arg4: () => A,
  }
) : void;

// ...3，4
declare func....

types({
  arg1: 'str',
  arg2: () => {
    return 18
  },
  arg3() {
    return ['str']
  },
  arg4: function() {
    return true
  },
})
```

This does not look like a simple sequence of priorities! Because arg2、arg3、arg4 are defined differently!

Comment: I dont understand the question

Comment: Are you asking: "in the following call, why is `A` is inferred to be `string` instead of possibly `number`, `string[]`, or `boolean`?"  If so, then you might want to come out and ask that explicitly.  Right now it isn't clear what you're asking about.

Comment: I don't understand what "declare syntax" has to do with anything, either.  Does something change if you use an implemented function as opposed to `declare`-ing one?  If not, then you should probably remove references to "declare syntax" from the question.

Comment: @jcalz Maybe I didn't make it clear. If you declare args in types<A> in the order of {arg1、arg2、arg3、arg4} and {arg2、arg1、arg3、arg4}, the types A is different!
so, the other order will lead to different results.

Comment: It would be nice for you to give a [mre] that clearly demonstrates what you're talking about without any unrelated errors or pseudocode, but I think I understand the question now. I'm not sure there's a great answer, though, since both versions result in an error, and the particular error message has to do with which candidate for `A` it tried first.  Like [this code](//tsplay.dev/N9pP7w) gives different error messages based only on ordering that shouldn't really matter. Do you have a version where no error happens and types depend on property order?